# QGIS Hangs on splash page at "Ready!"

Tags: windows, windows-10, crash

So I have one of our developers who is using QGIS that was working up until recently. He had QGIS 3.4 and it had begun to crash so we tried upgrading him to the latest version 3.16. It now hangs on the startup splash page at "ready!" but never launches. I have tried deleting his previous user profile from the /appdata in his user folder. So far I have not been able to get it to launch. The computer is a Windows 10 operating system 1909 or newer. Please help!

Answer (score 0):

I have not had such problems so far.

My suggestion is first to backup all projects on an (external) drive and a complete uninstall of version 3.4 and version 3.16. Because the originally used version 3.4 was a LTR, I think it is better to install here the current valid version 3.10.14 LTR.

Please also note the different versions for 32bit and 64bit.

Please note, QGIS will drop 32-bit Windows support in the next few months. QGIS 3.16 LTR will still be available for 32-bit systems. 32-bit support will be dropped during the process of updating Qt to version 5.15. Due to the complexity of the involved tasks, there is no fixed date for when this update will happen.

Comment: Thanks! I'll give this fresh install a shot.